# How to add fetch options to Workbox?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I need to add `credentials: 'same-origin'` to all fetch requests in order to make a PWA work in a password-protected website. Otherwise if I leave the website and come back later, the browser doesn't ask for my password and returns an Unauthorized error.

How do I do that with Workbox ? I noticed the `RequestWrapper` class includes fetchOptions, but I can't find a way to use them.

Comment: A couple of points of clarification: are you using Workbox v2 (the current stable release) or the alpha releases of v3? And do you need this to apply to precaching requests, runtime caching requests, or both?

Comment: @jeff-posnick, I'm using Workbox v2.1.2. I would need to apply this to both precaching requests and runtime caching requests. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v2, precaching should [already set](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/60d90262077c18e34240921fe0d36b876f5ca3b0/packages/workbox-precaching/src/lib/controllers/base-cache-manager.js#L32-L34) `credentials: 'same-origin'` as the `FetchOptions` on all outgoing requests.

For runtime caching, you can get this behavior by constructing your own `RequestWrapper` instance and passing that in to the runtime caching handler you're using:

```
const requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper({
  cacheName: 'my-cache-name', // Change this for each separate cache.
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  },
  plugins: [], // Add any plugins you need here, e.g. CacheExpiration.
});

const staleWhileRevalidateHandler = new StaleWhileRevalidate({requestWrapper});

workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/path/prefix'),
  staleWhileRevalidateHandler
);
```

(I'm not sure how you're using the Workbox libraries, but you may need to explicitly import additional scripts to get access to the `RequestWrapper` class, like https://unpkg.com/workbox-runtime-caching@2.0.3/build/importScripts/workbox-runtime-caching.prod.v2.0.3.js)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jess Posnick for the answer.
To avoid rewriting all workbox strategies, I ended up using a custom plugin:

```
const addFetchOptionsPlugin = {
  requestWillFetch: ({ request }) => new Request(request, { 
    credentials: 'same-origin', redirect: 'follow'
  })
};

workbox.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('my-route'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'my-cache',
    plugins: [addFetchOptionsPlugin]
  })
);
```